# Container is not lining up with a container next to it

Tags: html, css

I have two containers, one has a width of 30% and the other has a width of 70% however they are not inline, instead one moves lower and by passes the other container as seen in the screenshot below how can i fix this?

```
    main {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
      }

    aside {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    }
```

Here is the Screenshot

http://prntscr.com/jdsy9b

Thanks

Comment: look into `box-sizing: border-box;` for your elements. You think your `main` is 70% but it's actually 70% + 10px padding-left + 10px padding-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving `.main` `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
   .main {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
   }
```

This way you tell the browser to account for padding, you can read more about it in the [docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Oh yes that's true, How could i miss that.

Answer (score 0):

> **The padding actually increases the box width and height**

Here i removed the padding and added some height just to see the boxes.

```css
    .main {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height:100px;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
      }

    .aside {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width: 30%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="aside"> </div>
```